# MYSQL pivot with enhanced filter needed

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am pivotting the values from columns pe_date, pe_batch and pe_tarive into new columns c1, c2 and c3. Works well. But now I want to filter the date value from pe_date between Date1 and Date 2.

Where to place the WHERE BETWEEN Date1 and Date2 statement? Cannot figure it out. Thanks for helping!

```
SELECT t.submit_time,
 (SELECT field_value FROM mytable WHERE submit_time = t.submit_time AND field_name ='pe_date') as 'c1',
 (SELECT field_value FROM mytable WHERE submit_time = t.submit_time AND field_name ='pe_batch') as 'c2',
 (SELECT field_value FROM mytable WHERE submit_time = t.submit_time AND field_name ='pe_tarive') as 'c3'
FROM  mytable
GROUP BY t.submit_time
ORDER BY c1 ASC
```

Comment: See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 1):

I would write this using pivoting logic as:

```
SELECT
    submit_time,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'pe_date'   THEN field_value END) AS c1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'pe_batch'  THEN field_value END) AS c2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'pe_tarive' THEN field_value END) AS c3
FROM mytable
WHERE
    -- some restriction on the date
GROUP BY
    submit_time;
```

From what I can see, maybe you just need to add a `WHERE` clause.  The only other place where a restriction on dates might make sense would be the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Thanks Tim, adding: 

WHERE C1 BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-01-01'

Gives zero results although there is enough data in the table

Comment: Solved:

SELECT
    submit_time,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'pe_date'   THEN field_value END) AS c1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'pe_batch'  THEN field_value END) AS c2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'pe_tarive' THEN field_value END) AS c3
FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
GROUP BY submit_time
HAVING c1 BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'